# javascript excluding a particular tag from a div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to select on the text inside the alert excluding the `<a>` tag from javascript...

```
   <div id="addCompaniesModal" >
    <div class="alertBox costumAlertBox" style="display:inline-block;">
      <div class="alert alert-block alert-success fade in" style="display: block;">
         <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
         <strong>Success!</strong>
          Add Company: wxG50Z28 Success!
      </div>
    </div>
   </div
```

I tried below but it didnt work...

`successMessage = $('#addCompaniesModal .alert :not(.close)').text()`;
But it returns only **Success!**.. I I googled but didnt find a exact and simple way... one way i found was get the whole string and trim it which i dont want to do.... Can some geek help me .. .Thank YOu....

Comment: I wan't to -1 this for that some geek remark...

Comment: You googled it, that's good. But if google were capable to find an _exact_ match for you, there would be no need for professional developers. Programming isn't always _simple_. Look into the results you got when searching on google _read them_ and see how they might help you on your way. (tip: you're getting the text of a `strong` node, the other text is the contents of another node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say :not(.close)  it's telling jquery to return dom elements inside '#addCompaniesModal .alert' not everything that's inside of it.

Just wrap Add Company: wxG50Z28 Success! in a span:

http://jsfiddle.net/y4T2R/1/

```
  <div id="addCompaniesModal" >
    <div class="alertBox costumAlertBox" style="display:inline-block;">
      <div class="alert alert-block alert-success fade in" style="display: block;">
         <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
         <strong>Success!</strong>
          <span>Add Company: wxG50Z28 Success!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

At the best of my knowledge there is no such way. Try something else.